# how auto hide button after open activity?

Tags: java, android

I want auto hide button after open activity and after click item in ation bar show button

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int i = item.getItemId();
        Button bt_call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_call);
        if (i == R.id.action_hide) {
            if(button1IsVisible==true)
            {
                bt_call.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                button1IsVisible = false;
            }
            else if(button1IsVisible==false)
            {
                bt_call.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button1IsVisible = true;
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

Comment: you mean icon in the action bar ?

Comment: yes in action bar

Comment: above code is working on not?.. code works fine.

Comment: Any update ????

Answer (score 1):

when activity start set visibility of button hide..

```
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then in action bar's icon click listener...

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_other1:
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                           button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

                break;
            default:

                break;
        }

        // Return false to allow normal menu processing to proceed,
        // true to consume it here.
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check visibility of the particular button properly and then, show/hide. Below is a sample:

```
if (bt_call.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
   bt_call.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
   bt_call.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**Note:** Declare the buttons `Globally`, not inside the click event!

Comment: same problem.. after open activity don't hide auto button

Comment: declare the buttons `Globally` and then try it, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

> I want auto hide button after open activity and after click item in
>   ation bar show button

At first you need to set `bt_call` to invisible in `onCreate` method like what @Devyani Kotadiya said

```
Button bt_call;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_xml); 
    bt_call= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_call);
    bt_call.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 }
```

Then implements as below

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_hide:
            if (button1IsVisible.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            {
                bt_call.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else
                bt_call.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```